Alexa skill There was a problem with the requested skill's response
class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Skill Launch."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

        return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        logger.info("In LaunchRequestHandler")
        #attr= inc_launch_counter(handler_input)
        
        if True :
            logger.info("Free quota exceeded")
            speak_output = (
                "You've used this skill more than 10 times! Would you like to buy the premium version to unlock more features?")
            
            return (
                handler_input.response_builder
                    .add_directive(
                        SendRequestDirective(
                            name="Buy",
                            payload={
                                "InSkillProduct": {
                                    "productId": "amzn1.adg.product.2b22d53f-7605-4b09-aef0-dcdbaedaded3",  
                                }
                            },
                            token= "sdfffsd",
                        )
                    ).set_should_end_session(False)
                    .response
            )
            
            
        response_builder=handler_input.response_builder
        url = create_presigned_url("Media/shh-sound.mp3") #ak1.wav
        logger.info(f"url = {url}")
        # Using URL as token as they are all unique
        response_builder.add_directive(
            PlayDirective(
                play_behavior=PlayBehavior.REPLACE_ALL,
                audio_item=AudioItem(
                    stream=Stream(
                        token="test2-ad",
                        url=url,
                        offset_in_milliseconds=0,
                        expected_previous_token=None),
                    metadata=None
                )
            )
        ).set_should_end_session(True)
        
        return response_builder.response


{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
            "directives": [
                {
                    "type": "Connections.SendRequest",
                    "name": "Buy",
                    "payload": {
                        "InSkillProduct": {
                            "productId": "amzn1.adg.product.2b22d53f-7605-4b09-aef0-dcdbaedaded3"
                        }
                    },
                    "token": "sdfffsd"
                }
            ],
            "shouldEndSession": false,
            "type": "_DEFAULT_RESPONSE"
        },
        "sessionAttributes": {},
        "userAgent": "ask-python/1.19.0 Python/3.8.20"
    }
}

